# jquery menu - fade in/out

Tags: jquery

I'm building a simple menu with jquery and am having trouble getting it to stay visible on rollover.

here is my jQ:

```
$('.process').hover(function(){
            $('#dropdown').fadeIn(1000);    
        }, function(){
            $('#dropdown').delay(1000).fadeOut();
    });

$('#dropdown').mouseover(function() {
        //Need something here to hold the menu
    });
$('#dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
```

What do I need above?

here is semi working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kenaesthetic/L25MD/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UL#dropdown should be inside the LI that contains .process, and .process should be on the li, not on the a. This makes #dropdown a child of li.process, and therefore the hover doesn't end while you're in li.process.

I started reworking your fiddle, but it'll take some CSS adjustment to get it all working.

UPDATE (based on the fiddle in your comment below):

http://jsfiddle.net/L25MD/11/

```
$('li.process').hover(function () {
    $('#dropdown').fadeIn(1000);
}, function () {
    $('#dropdown').delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Of course... Look here. It still isn't quite working. http://jsfiddle.net/kenaesthetic/L25MD/10/

Comment: You still have .process on <a> rather than on <li>.